# How to fix permissions with Repair Disk Permissions?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, permission

I just installed Xcode 5.1 and the latest round of updates. I followed that with a *Repair Disk Permissions*. For some reason, Apple installs its software with broken permissions.

I then ran *Repair Disk Permissions* (*Applications → Utilities → Disk Utility*):

[image]

Now, XQuartz will not start:

[image]

In the above, Xquartz cannot write to `/tmp` after the permission repair because *Repair Disk Permissions* remove `w` from the link.

It appears the permissions in *Disk Utility* are broken out of the box, too. How does one modify the permission used by *Disk Utility* so that the utility will not break an installation? Is there a plist somewhere that can be tweaked?

I've been suffering these types of problems for years. Its like a death from 10,000 cuts. Why does Apple *not* test their software before unleashing it on unsuspecting users?

Comment: Are you asking how to change permissions on tmp or how to change the expected permissions on tmp?

Comment: I just checked the permissions of my /tmp and it is 733, same as your example.

Comment: Thanks @Fyrefly - I'd like to know how to modify the permissions used/applied by Disk Utility. I expect its in a plist or data file somewhere. If they are hard coded into Disk Utility, then I'm probably out of luck.

Comment: Its my understanding Disk Utility references    /Library/Receipts       for installed software, I don't know what it references for base system files.

Comment: My Mac used to always mess up the /tmp write permissions by itself, causing copy/paste and dragging to stop working. It doesn't anymore, and I don't know why.